# Android device stops sending location after sometime

Tags: android, location, android-geofence

I am trying to learn Location Services in android and I am doing an android project app in which I send locations of a user in periodic intervals to server after he has left the house. Whenever user leaves the house, the code in app starts tracking the user. I also have a code in which I set up a geofence around user's house which when is tripped changes the priority from BALANCED to HIGH_ACCURACY and reduce the interval of sending locations to the server. Also.
The code looks like this: I have a locationWatcher class in which I initialize my intent:

```
 final Intent locationIntent = new Intent(context, LocationReceiver.class);
 mLocationIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    context, 111 /*requestCode*/, locationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

final Intent geoFenceIntent = new Intent(context, LocationReceiver.class);
geoFenceIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_GEO_FENCE, true);
mGeoFenceIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    context, 113/*requestCode*/, geoFenceIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Then whenever, I get a location change or geofence trip, My Location Receiver class wakes up and starts the LocationService and passes the intent to it, so that I can send the location to the server.

This code works fine, but in some cases, the device stops sending location after sometime. I am unable to figure out why it is happening in few cases. I need to keep sending locations till user has returned back to his home. After which my app will stop sending locations to the server.

I have all the required permissions in my app and I have tried it both on Nougat and Marshmallow and both show the same problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the device stationary when it is not sending GPS? Does it ever resume, ie if you begin moving? Is your application active or in the background when this occurs?

Comment: The device is always with the user whether he is in car or walking. Yes it resumes when the user starts walking or driving. The application can be active/in background or dead. It works beautifully in many cases but sometimes it fails without any clue. Is android killing something in background?? I am really not sure...

Comment: When requesting location updates did you perhaps specify a minimum displacement? Then there would be no location updates when the device remains still. And of course there won't be location updates if the device is indoors outside the reach of GPS signals.

Comment: No, I have not specified any condition.

Comment: I seem to have the same issue. After a couple of days the fused location provider just stops sending new location intents. The problem started for me after upgrading my device to Nougat. Were you able to solve this?

Comment: No not yet. But do you know if this a known Nougat issue?